# Python/Kivy game for steam

Tags: python, steam

I'm developing a game in Python with Kivy as the gui. I've heard a few programs mentioned that compile python files to .exe's. However, I cant seem to find any that mention compiling .py and .kv files.

I wish to eventually publish my game to Steam Direct but i would like to know if my current approach to coding the game will hinder me doing so.

My actual question is, is there a way to compile a Python game with Kivy to an .exe file?

Comment: Gamedev SE typically does not welcome [questions about which technologies to use in your game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). However, it sounds like what you're really asking is either "Is there a way to compile a Python game with Kivy to an .exe file?" or "Can Python games be distributed on Steam?". I would suggest rewording the question to be more specific.

Comment: You didn't even tried to search the answer on the web? Yes, there is a way to compile Python. https://askubuntu.com/questions/324871/how-to-compile-a-python-file

Comment: im not asking how to compile python, im asking how to compile python when using kivy and kivy files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, i found the answer hidden within their docs https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html

You then need to set `console=True` to `console=False` within the .spec file to disable the console from being shown. Once you create the .spec file, you will see which line it is

Comment: ill accept it as the right answer when it lets me so others can find it